# Valgrind: Wrong Version

Tags: valgrind

I downloaded Valgrind 3.7.0 and ran:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

However when I run valgrind --version, I get 3.5.0. How is this possible? I am running Mac OS X Lion 10.7. I know I downloaded 3.7.0 because the tar file I downloaded from Valgrind's website name is`valgrind-3.7.0`.

What other ways can I check for the version?

Comment: What is the result of executing `which valgrind` And what is the result of executing `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @ArjunShankar `which valgrind`: `/usr/local/bin/valgrind`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, valgrind binaries should get installed in `/usr/local/bin` when you compile from source without providing a `--prefix`.

(You *really just did* `./configure && make && make install` and had the permissions to install, right?)

1. See if `/usr/local/bin/valgrind` exists.
2. Execute `/usr/local/bin/valgrind --version`. What is the version?
3. Execute `which valgrind`. This should tell you where the valgrind binary is being picked from. Is it the same? My guess is, it is probably not.
4. Execute `echo $PATH` to see your path. This gives a `:` delimited list of directories where `bash` searches for executables, *in the order* in which the directories are listed.

My guess is:

There is an existing `valgrind` installation of the old version, and it shows up in a directory that appears earlier in your `$PATH` than `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: That's correct. I had a different valgrind version installed previously. Why didn't my newer installation override the older one if installing without `--prefix` installs it in `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: I'm not sure because I don't know your `$PATH` and I don't know where your earlier valgrind binary is installed. Like I explained, bash searches directories in the order in which they appear in `$PATH`. It picks the binary which is found first.